# replace / with \/ in js string

Tags: javascript

Basically the title. How do you replace `/` with `\/` using `replace` fn?

This doesn't work:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".replace(/\//g,"\/")
```

this also doesn't work:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".replace(/\//g,"\\/")
```

Comment: your second example works for me

Comment: You don’t typically need to replace forward slash in strings.

Comment: Keep in mind that ``\`` will show as ``\\`` in the logging since the backslash needs to be escaped and logging shows escapes. `\/` won't show just `\/` because forward slashes don't need to be escaped. So you'll either get `/` or `\\/` but never `\/`.

Comment: @Ouroborus aa thats why  I keep getting wrong string

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the correct string. Internally, `\\/` is actually/literally `\/`, it's only printed `\\/` to show that the backslash is a backslash rather than the backslash escaping the forward slash.

Comment: @Ouroborus feel free to post you comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` function only replaces the first occurence of your string, so to replace all of them, you can combine `split` and `join` like that :

```js
const str = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"

console.log(str.split('/').join('\\/'))
```